# Show preview of wordpress posts on external html sever

Tags: html, blog-page, previews, wp-blog-header.php

I used to have this working, however, ionos started chartging me for having wordpress, when I said I am not paying for a free site they deleted access to my blog. All the program files are there but I cannot get my posts. I have had to remake my blog on the actual wordpress and it all links together fine. However, the code I was using looks for wp-blog-header.php located on the same server. What I need to be able to do is to access this file on the word press site. Currently my code is:

```
<?php
// Include WordPress
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
// Change path below to location of wp-blog-header.php on server
require('/****/homepages/45/********/htdocs/clickandbuilds//wp-blog-header.php');
// Change number below to show 1 or more post excerpts
query_posts('showposts=3');
```

?>

I have tried changing it to  require('https://mysite.wordpress.com/wp-blog-header.php');
but it cannot load and crashes my site.
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required

My question is fairly simple, how do I access the required file?

Also as my access through ionos, because they have blocked me from logging in to wordpress onboard my server, does this mean I have to bootstrap wordpress in order for the functions to work?
Since they deleted my access the onboard wordpress, my site didn't break as it was still calling the required function, and getting a return, but no data was showing up in my blog previews.

Unfortunately, it seems hard to find straight and simple information on this as it always refers to using wordpress installed server side. Thanks

Comment: WordPress runs on the server side, but you can get the posts' content via the [REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/). This won't apply the site's theme to the posts, because the themes run on the server side too, but you'll get the content and you'll be able to access the posts' metadata as well.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for taking the trouble to reply, I do appreciate it. I don't need the theme I just need the data contained within, so it sounds like this will be the avenue to explore. Unfortunately my knowledge of php and javascript is rudimentary, I'm conversant with microcontrollers and c++, so all this sort of programming is beyond me presently. Hopefully its not too difficult to implement lol. Thanks for spelling this out to me plainly.